# XSLT transformation group by element

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello all i trying to learn XSLT transformation but i stuck in this moment when i wanna grouped by category, counting the number of records, which fall into this category and sum of the field sum.

For example my xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<root>
    <row>
        <prid>1</prid>
        <product>Name 1</product>
        <category>Cat 1</category>
        <price>23</price>
        <qty>9</qty>
        <sum>44</sum>
    </row>
    <row>
        <prid>2</prid>
        <product>Name 2</product>
        <category>Cat 3</category>
        <price>10</price>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <sum>22</sum>
    </row>
</root>
```

And my xsl file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Prid</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Product</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Category</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Qty</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Sum</th>
                    </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each-group select="/root/row" group-by="category">
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="prid" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="product" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="category" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="price" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/sum)" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each-group>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If have someone can help me to where i wrong and explain it to me. Thanks

Comment: So which result exactly do you want to create for that sample having just two `row` elements with different `category` child element values? Do you get any error for your XSLT attempt? The use of `for-each-group` and `sum(current-group())` or `sum(current-group()/sum)` alone seems to be fine if you really use an XSLT 2 processor, it it not clear which output exactly you want for each group.

Comment: Yea, i have a error : 
Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT transformation failed.

Comment: Didn't you say earlier you are using XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Yes but in this moment i use version 2.0

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced using the code you have posted: http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uB7 If you're using a XSLT 2.0 processor, you should see a more detailed error message.

Comment: The use of the `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>` directive in your XML suggests the transformation is being done in the browser (i.e. You just open the XML in a browser, and it does the transformation using the stylesheet in the directive). In this case, it will be an XSLT 1.0 processor that is used.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said very clearly what output you want, and you haven't said very clearly what output you are getting. You also haven't told us how you are running the transformation (what XSLT processor, and how invoked).

The code as written is correct. It's a little bit strange in that you are grouping, and then not producing any output that makes the grouped structure visible, but perhaps that's what you want.

You say you're getting an error message. You've only told us about a summary message that says it failed: somewhere there will be detailed messages that tell you why it failed. If you're not seeing those messages then you need to tell us what processor you are running and how, so we can tell you where to find them.

It's a common mistake to think you are running an XSLT 2.0 processor when you aren't. Some people imagine that putting "version='2.0'" at the top of the stylesheet is all you need to do. But if you send a stylesheet saying "version='2.0'" to a processor that was written in 2001 and only understands 1.0, it's not going to take any notice of that.

Comment: So... The problem is in the browsers... And dont know why.
When i put the data from the files in http://xslttest.appspot.com/
Everything is correctly.

Comment: @AleksandurAtanasov Browsers use XSLT 1.0 Your stylesheet requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the answer .

Comment: @AleksandurAtanasov Use Muenchian grouping, as I suggested earlier.

Comment: Or if you want XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0) in the browser, try Saxon-JS.